# Sqlalchemy session.refresh does not refresh object

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following mapping (straight from SA examples):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

I'm working with a MySql DB and the table has an innoDB engine.

I have a single record in my table:
1|'user1'|'user1 test'|'password'

I've opened a session with the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

db_engine = create_engine('mysql://...@localhost/test_db?charset=utf8',echo=False,pool_recycle=1800)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine,autocommit=False,autoflush=False)
session_maker = scoped_session(session_factory)
session = session_maker()

user_1 = session.query(User).filter(User.id==1).one()
user_1.name # This prints: u'user1'
```

Now, when I change the record's name in the DB to 'user1_change' and commit it and then refresh the object like this:

```
session.refresh(user_1)
user_1.name # This still prints: u'user1' and not u'user1_change'
```

It still prints: u'user1' and not u'user1_change'.

What am I missing (or setting up wrong) here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you used to commit the name change? Is the name actually changed in the database?

Comment: Or by "when I change the record's name in the DB", you mean you change the record using some other means than the SQLAlchemy session (e.g., using something like phpMyAdmin)?

Comment: working with mysql-workbech, I changed the value in the db and committed, totally under SQLalchemy's radar - but that shouldn't matter,right?

Comment: I still not able to solve this problem. I tried everything but no use. How did you fix this?

Comment: @jasper we didn't, this might be related to the storage engine such that not all engines support this action :(

Comment: I'm in the very same situation. I remember in the past that I did the "db.session.commit()" trick and worked, so I have no idea about what's going on this time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.refresh):

> Note that a highly isolated transaction will return the same values as were previously read in that same transaction, regardless of changes in database state outside of that transaction

SQLAlchemy uses a transactional unit of work model, wherein each transaction is assumed to be internally consistent.  A session is an interface on top of a transaction.  Since a transaction is assumed to be internally consistent, SQLAlchemy will only (well, not quite, but for ease of explanation...) retrieve a given piece of data from the database and update the state of the associated objects once per transaction.  Since you already queried for the object in the same session transaction, SQLAlchemy will not update the data in that object from the database again within that transaction scope.  If you want to poll the database, you'll need to do it with a fresh transaction each time.

Comment: This makes sense, but what I'm not understanding is when will refreshing or updating will make the session re fetch from the DB, I mean, that's what refresh and expire are suppose to do, break the transaction,no?

Comment: Objects attached to the session don't need to have been loaded from the database.  They could have been constructed or modified locally or merged in from a different session.  Transactional scope only guarantees that data will only be *read from the database* once per transaction, not that state of a mapped object will only change once per transaction.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand what you're saying here - session.refresh and session.expire will work only on table engines which do not enforce transactions?

Can you describe a case where refresh will work?

Comment: I don't claim expertise in this area, but from how it reads to me, if you were, for instance, to merge an object in to a session, you can expire/refresh that object to force it to update within the new session, provided that no query was made against that object within that transaction.

Answer (score 10):

session.refresh() didn't work for me either. Even though I saw a low-level SELECT the object was not updated after the refresh.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121788/562267 hints to doing an actual  commit/rollback to reset the session, and that worked for me:

```
user_1 = session.query(User).filter(User.id==1).one()
user_1.name # This prints: u'user1'
# update the database from another client here
session.commit()
user_1 = session.query(User).filter(User.id==1).one()
user_1.name # Should be updated now.
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with "expire" as described in the official doc:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#refreshing-expiring

```
# expire objects obj1, obj2, attributes will be reloaded
# on the next access:
session.expire(user_1)
session.refresh(user_1)
```

Using expire on a object results in a reload that will occur upon next access.

Comment: I did, this does not effect the object in session

Answer (score -1):

Merge the session.

```
u = session.query(User).get(id)
u.name = 'user1_changed'
u = session.merge(u)
```

This will update the database and return the newer object.

Comment: Did this work for you? I've tried it as well and am still getting the same values..

Comment: According to how the docs read, this shouldn't work.  You'd have to merge the object in to a newly created session.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the commit().  I normally use a context manager for the transaction block.

Comment: @SilasRay, you are correct.  I'm using .flush() now, and it seems to work well.